# determine the time when the windows system is waked up from the sleep

Tags: c#

Can any one tell how to determine the time at which the windows pc is waked up from sleep? **using C#**.

I know how to get the time when the computer is powered on.

Comment: Please visit this topic:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18206183/event-to-detect-system-wake-up-from-sleep-in-c-sharp

Comment: You could [inspect the System event log](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k6b9a7h8%28v=vs.90%29.aspx). My Windows 7 PC logs an event from source Power-Troubleshooter when the system resumes from suspend mode.

Comment: Also see http://stackoverflow.com/a/10854355/1198986

Comment: To everyone saying "visit this topic" or likewise, please click the flag link under the question and mark this question as a duplicate of the other.

Answer (score 0):

You can visit [this site](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18206183/event-to-detect-system-wake-up-from-sleep-in-c-sharp) to detect when the pc wakes up or sleeps
Also you can use the Stopwatch class to get the time.

```
private void SystemEvents_PowerModeChanged(object sender, PowerModeChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        switch (e.Mode)
        {
            // Cuando regresa del sleep 
            case PowerModes.Resume:
                sleepStopwatch.Stop();
                break;
            // Cuando se va en sleep
            case PowerModes.Suspend:
                sleepStopwatch.Start(); 
                break;
        }
    }
```