# How do we find out how long it's been since we pressed the power button on a computer?

Tags: c++, c, windows, winapi

I tried the Windows API functions, but I did not understand which one meets my request. Like `GetTickCount64`, `QueryInterruptTime` etc. How can I calculate it?

Comment: I always use the duration from the network adapter.  Maybe you can get that?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Programmatically getting system boot up time in c++ (windows)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10853985/programmatically-getting-system-boot-up-time-in-c-windows)

Comment: Are you really sure you need something as specific as "time since power button was pressed" rather than something more sensible like "time since last boot"?

Comment: There is no way for you to determine the last time the power button was pressed. For all we know, a machine may not even have a power button. If you meant to ask a different question, [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/46794795/edit) it.

Answer (score 0):

[`GetTickCount64`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724411(v=vs.85).aspx) returns the number of milliseconds since the last boot. This should be enough.

Answer (score -2):

[image]

You can also use `GetTickCount()`. Like this:

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){

    int hours;
    int min;
    int sec;
    int rem1;

    int nSysUpTime = GetTickCount() / 1000;
    int days = nSysUpTime / 60 / 60 / 24;
    hours = nSysUpTime / 3600;
    rem1 = nSysUpTime % 3600;
    min = rem1 / 60;
    sec = rem1 % 60;


    printf( "\nComputer Uptime   %02d:%02d:%02d \n\n",hours , min  ,sec  );


return 0;
}
```

Comment: `GetTickCount()` wraps back to 0 every 49.7 days of continuous running. A computer may run much longer than that. Use `GetTickCount64()` instead.